# How to make the border of a SimplePanel dashed?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT application with some `SimplePanel`.

How can I make its border dashed?

I tried `myPanel.addStyleName(Style.BorderStyle.DOTTED.getCssName());`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work using [Element#getStyle()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getStyle%28%29) method to update the element's [Style](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html) object.

```
SimplePanel myPanel=new SimplePanel();
myPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
```

but I suggest you to keep the styling in the CSS file instead of directly applying it in Java file that is more difficult to manage and change in future mostly in case of themes.

CSS:

```
.dashedBorder{
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

JAVA:

```
SimplePanel myPanel=new SimplePanel();
myPanel.setStyleName("dashedBorder");
```